# How do i bind a bindingsource created from stored procedure to a gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

Firstly, I have 3 tables in my database:

| Student |
| --- |
| StudentID |
| Name |
| Adress |
| OtherInfo |

| TuitionFee |
| --- |
| StudentID |
| Years |
| Semester |
| FeeAmount |

| Detailed_TuitionFee |
| --- |
| StudentID |
| Years |
| Semester |
| PaymentDate |
| PaymentAmount |

Then I created a stored procedure to select some column on `[TuitionFee ]` and `[Detailed_TuitionFee ]` with `StudentID` as parameter.

```
create procedure 
    @StudentID
as 
begin
    select 
    from [TuitionFee ]
    left outer join [Detailed_TuitionFee ] on TuitionFee.StudentID = Detailed_TuitionFee.StudentID 
                                           and TuitionFee.Semester = Detailed_TuitionFee.Semester
    where TuitionFee.StudentID = @StudentID 
      and Detailed_TuitionFee.StudentID = @StudentID
```

In C#, the code I wrote is

```
BindingSource bdsTuitionInfo = new BindingSource();
String studentID; 
GridControl gCtrlTuition;
GridView gViewTuition;
String sqlCmd = "exec Stored procedure" + studentID;

DataTable dt = Program.ExecSqlDataTable(sqlCmd); // create a Data table from SP
bdsTuitionInfo.DataSource = dt; // import data table into Binding source
gCtrlTuition.DataSource = bdsTuitionInfo; // import Binding source into Grid Control
gViewTuition.DataSource = bdsTuitionInfo; // The code shows ERROR: "Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" here
```

How do I show the data from this `BindingSource` in the `GridView`?
Is there anything to adjust or configure in my `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used DevExpress' grid but their [official example](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView#example) appears to indicate that a GridView is not something you need to assign a DataSource on; you assign the source to the GridControl and then maybe access the GridView via the GridControl to set other properties..

```
        gridControl1.DataSource = DataHelper.GetData(30);
        // The grid automatically creates columns for the public fields found in the data source. 
        // Calling the gridView1.PopulateColumns method is not required unless the gridView1.OptionsBehavior.AutoPopulateColumns is disabled

        // The grid automatically creates a GridView that presents the underlying data as a two-dimensional table.
        GridView gridView1 = gridControl1.MainView as GridView;

        GridView;

        // Obtain created columns.
        GridColumn colCompany = gridView1.Columns["CompanyName"];
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!! This is what i actually need. The GridView now can display rows from my Stored procedure. Have a good day sir.

Answer (score 1):

at first fill your data into datatable dt. then just add GridView control on your page. then use (if you use ASP.NET Web Form):

```
GridView.DataSource = dt;
//GridView.Databind(); //just in asp.net webform
```

There is a Grid View control in ASP.NET Web Form and I think you use it.
[image]

Comment: I'm working on Winform project build with DevExpress components. Therefore i don't know about which line is from ASP.NET here. I tried 2 lines you recommend but they show ERROR: "CS0200: Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" and ERROR: ""GridView" does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no accessible extension method 'DataBind'".

Comment: DataBind just works in ASP.NET Webforms. at first you should define columns with true names in DxGridControls. then fill data into datatable. then bind data to DxGrigControl. When you add gridcontrol on the form you can see the small form in bottom of the gridcontrol than contains two button. click on *Run Designer* and define your columns.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nfFr.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I didn't have any defined columns in GridView so the data didn't show either. It's my first time working on DevExpress with a DataTable which isn't from DataSource (also my first time working with C# and DevExpress), so I messed up a lot. Wish you a nice day sir.